# The numbers never occur next to each other

Tags: java

I wrote a program that reads an array of integers and two numbers `n` and `m`. The program check that `n` and `m` never occur next to each other (in any order) in the array.

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        int len = scanner.nextInt();
        int [] array = new int [len];

        boolean broken = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            array [i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int m = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int j = 1; j < len; j++){
           if((array[j]==n)&&(array[j+1]==m) || (array[j]==n)&&(array[j-1]==m) || (array[j]==m)&&(array[j+1]==n) || (array[j]==m)&&(array[j-1]==n)){
                broken = true;
                break;

            }
        }
        System.out.println(broken);
    }
}
```

Test input:

```
3
1 2 3
3 4
```

Correct output: true

My output is blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you don't get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as you are using `array[j+1]` whereas you have loop condition as `j < len`. The condition should be `j < len -1`.

The following works as expected:

```
for (int j = 1; j < len - 1; j++) {
    if ((array[j] == n && array[j + 1] == m) || (array[j] == n && array[j - 1] == m)
            || (array[j] == m && array[j + 1] == n) || (array[j] == m && array[j - 1] == n)) {
        broken = true;
        break;

    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
3
1 2 3
3 4
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because of `array[j+1]` where j can be `len-1`. Actually you don't need to check both sides(previous and next element), checking combination with previous is enough since in the next iteration combination with next element will be checked.

```
for (int j = 1; j < len; j++){
   if((array[j]==n && array[j-1]==m) || (array[j]==m && array[j-1]==n)){
        broken = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int len = scan.nextInt();
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0, prv = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        if (!map.containsKey(num))
            map.put(num, new HashSet<>());

        if (i > 0)
            map.get(prv).add(num);

        prv = num;
    }

    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int m = scan.nextInt();
    boolean res = !map.containsKey(n) || !map.containsKey(m) || !map.get(n).contains(m) && !map.get(m).contains(n);
    System.out.println(res);
}
```